# Regex match lines that are not commented

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a string read from a JavaScript file, that will have:

```
...
require('some/path/to/file.less');
...
// require('some/path/to/file.less');
...
```

I'm using this reg-ex:

```
requireRegExp = /require(\ +)?\((\ +)?['"](.+)?['"](\ +)?\)\;?/g
```

To catch all those lines. However, I need to filter out the ones that are commented.

So when I run

```
while( match = requireRegExp.exec(str) ){
...
}
```

I will only get a match for the uncommented line that starts with require...

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\/\/[^\r\n]*/g, '');`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need but `regequireRegExp = /^require.+/g` worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regequireRegExp = /^\s*require\('([^']+)'\);/gm`

Explanation:

`^` assert position at start of a line

`\s*` checks for a whitespace character 0 ... many times

`require` matches the word require

`\(` matches the character `(`

`'` matches the character `'`

`([^']+)`matches anything that isnt a `'` 1 ... many times

Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

`'` matches the character `'` literally

`\)` matches the character `)` literally

`;` matches the character `;` literally

`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

`m` modifier: multi-line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

**EDIT**

Apparently you wanted to get the path in a group so I edited my answer to better respond to your question.

Here is the example:

https://regex101.com/r/kQ0lY8/3

Comment: thanks @Alex, but what about if the line is idented?

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, seeing that first part of Amal's solution seems to have no effect... i ask you to edit with my complete regex, adding account for the possible white space beforre the begining of the line.
 /^(\s+)?require(\+)?\((\ +)?['"](.+)?['"](\ +)?\)\;?/gm

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez There you go! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match only those with `require` use the following:

```
/^\s*require.*/gm
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE4yT4/7)

Comment: Explain downvotes please? So that I could improve the answer?

Comment: "*regex to not match if line commented*" -- the OP wants to NOT match the line if is commented. This does the opposite.